# First major release from git

Tags: git

I have just released V1.0.0 of a product from git and I am wondering what the recommended advice is from now.

Do I create a v1.0.0 branch or is a v1.0.0 annotated tag, a better alternative?

A tag seems the right approach to me but I am unsure of the workflow of branching and merging from the tag.

Comment: If you make the release before you make the tag, you've already missed the boat.  Making an annotated tag should occur before you release.  In fact, by many definitions, making the annotated tag *is* making the release.

Comment: As long as you know the commit where the release was done it doesn't matter when you tag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catch phrase has been expressed on StackOverflow elsewhere:

> Branches are for work, tags are for releases.

Your mainline branch (usually master) should be continuos forward development for the next release. Each time a release is made use a tag (annotated at a minimum) to mark the event.

If you need to make a maintenance release for a released version while you are working on the next version, you can checkout the tag, and create the branch from that point.

```
git checkout -b <tag>-maintenance <tag>
```

This will create a new branch for your maintenance work. You will follow the same process on the maintenance branch by tagging the release on the maintenance branch when you are finished with the maintenance release.

If there is no other forward development on the release (master) branch, you can just add the maintenance work onto that branch, tag again, and move on.

Comment: Are you saying that for every potential bug fix, I would create a branch off the current tag.  Fix the bug or new feature, create a new tag and merge upstream to the master?

Comment: Not every bug fix individually. That would be insane. :-) and not features. Features are planned and go into scheduled releases. This would be for a bug fix release. That is, you have released 2.1 and you are working on 2.2. Changes on 2.2 are on the main branch (master). But now you've discovered several bugs in 2.1 that need to be fixed. 2.2 is a ways down the road yet. So, you want to release 2.1.1. Create the branch at 2.1, make the changes for 2.1.1, merge, tag and release.

Answer (score 1):

With git you're free to create branch at any time! I would do the following:

1. Create tag 'v1.0.0'
2. When I need to add some fix to version 1.0.0, I would create a branch 'v1.0.0-maintenance' based on my tag.
3. If you want to take the fix to current version, merge 'v1.0.0-maintenance' to 'master' or use cherry-pick

Answer (score 0):

Depends, but I assume you will want to continue to fix v.1.0.0 quite soon while working on the next version as well.

I'd create a branch straight away. It's highly unlikely that you won't need it (only case would be that you never need to create v1.0.1).

You can of course also tag it (never hurts) and then later create the branch based on that tag. You can create a branch from a tag simply with

```
git checkout -b 1.0.0 v1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

An annotated tag is probably the first thing you should do.

From there, you have several choices for your workflow: here are two of the most common options.

You can move on in a "forward-only" style of development, where the 1.0 series is never supported anymore (1); you can do "support-only" on 1.0 series and all new features get added to the 2.0 series (or substitute 1.0.1 and 1.1, leaving 2.0 for a full rewrite -- the version numbers aren't that important) (2).

Scenario 2 is definitely the more "professional" option, but if it's a smaller project with a narrow scope, Scenario 1 is okay.

In Scenario 1, you can either do all your work in the master branch, or do feature branches, merging into master when ready.  When you have a new release, just tag it as 1.1 or 1.0.1 or whatever.

In Scenario 2, you can use your master branch to reflect the newest release, a "support" branch to reflect your support release, a "staging" branch to stage and test new features that will eventually get merged into master, and you can use feature branches for development of new features or bug fixes.  And as you deploy bug fixes, you'll merge the support branch back into master.  When you release either a new version or a support version, just use an annotated tag again.

Personally, I'm usually in favor of the master-staging-support branch with tags, rather than having a branch for each versioned release; but that's the great thing about git -- you can do it however you see fit!  So of course, the two options I've presented are by no means the only options you have for your development workflow.

Comment: So I tag the repo at 1.0.0 and create a 1.0.0 support branch is what you are saying for scenario 2.  I thought I could use the tag as the support branch rather than creating another branch.

Comment: @dagda1: A tag can be thought of similar to an "extra note" on a commit.  You use a tag when you want to know exactly which commit corresponds to something particular -- in this case, the commit that was used to build version 1.0.0 of the software.  On the other hand, a branch is just a named pointer to commits, that can move as you make more commits.  So tags are important *after* development, branches are important *during* development.

Comment: @daga1: No, the branch from "v1.0.0" tag will definitely not be called "1.0.0", simply because it's not 1.0.0 (that's the tag only). It's branch that will lead to "1.0.x", so it can be called "support`, "maint"(enance), "prev", or, if you plan to support more than 1 release back, something like "maint-1.0" is suitable.